# How to have more than 1 Class in PowerMock SuppressStaticInitializationFor Annotation

Tags: java, annotations, powermock, powermockito

How to have more than 1 Class in PowerMock SuppressStaticInitializationFor class level Annotation.

This works fine with 1 class.

```
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("org.foo.FooClass")
```

I can't figure out how to put more than 1 class in this annotation even though the JavaDoc (see below) says that you can.

[Annotation Type SuppressStaticInitializationFor JavaDoc](http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.6.5/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/SuppressStaticInitializationFor.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought I already tried this, but I guess I didn't.

**Solution:**

```
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor({"org.foo.FooClass1","org.foo.FooClass2"})
```